# Immplement AbstractTableModel , make column JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing

I want to implement an abstract class `AbstractTableModel`, and specify that the first column shall be of type `JFormattedTextField`.

How do I do that?

Comment: You might start by having a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

Comment: Some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20jformattedtextfield%20table%20tablecellrenderer).